# Animating rectangle: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

So far this is what I've got:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void TestMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveTo(imageTest, 100, 100);
    }
    public static void MoveTo(this Image target, double newX, double newY)
    {
        var top = Canvas.GetTop(target);
        var left = Canvas.GetLeft(target);
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        target.RenderTransform = trans;
        DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(top, newY - top,     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(left, newX - left, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim1);
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim2);
    }
}
```

It has an error code of

> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

The premise is just to move a rectangle using an animation/timer, however using WPFs make it harder to do so, any help, or even better ways of doing so, would be helpful!

Comment: Why didn't just make this method "normal" static instead extension?(or just follow any other answer for this problem) *however using WPFs make it harder* how WPF can make something harder?

Comment: The error message can't be more clear. You have to declare the MoveTo method in another class. Or simply replace `this Image target` by `Image target`, which turns it into a reguar static method instead of an extension method.

Comment: Even better: `UIElement target`. Now you can use the method not only for Image elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are expecting `this Image` as the parameter in `MoveTo`, it is considering this method as an extension method. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). Try this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void TestMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveTo(imageTest, 100, 100);
    }
    public static void MoveTo(UIElement target, double newX, double newY)
    {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone!  I appreciate the advice, although it may seem "obvious" and "easy" I'm still learning C#, and have been learning it for the past month, I'm new to the programming scene and I am still getting to grips with its basic concepts